# What is the purpose of the "Merge" tab shown in the synonym page?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, moderator-abilities

When I merge two tags, and the operation is completed, the page shows a link to the synonym page; if I click on that link, I am redirected to the "Merge" tab of that page, which is always empty.

What is the purpose of that tab?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge tab lists all synonyms that are pending a merger. Whether or not there will be any depends mostly on the prudence of the moderators of that site. Thus, if most synonyms are created by the moderators (who generally merge while doing so), then it's almost always going to be empty.

I imagine the direction there is that, after you've performed a merge of your own, that you might want to look at any pending jobs that may exist.

Comment: As secondary question: which users can propose a tag merge?

Comment: @kiam Pending mergers are just synonyms where there are existing questions that still have the sub-tags. Thus, any time two existing tags are synonym'd by a normal user, it will present a merge opportunity.

Comment: I got it; thank you. I was thinking it were possible to propose merging two tags in the same way it is possible to propose synonyms, but I see that they are not two separated things.